# is_foo struct inside a templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a `foo` struct templated on a `size_t`. I want to write an `is_foo` struct such that `is_foo<T>::value` is true if and only if `T` looks like `foo<N>` for some `N`. Here is a minimal example of my issue:

```
template<typename T>
class Bar {
public:
    template<size_t N> struct foo{};
    template<typename> struct is_foo : std::false_type{};
    template<size_t N> struct is_foo<foo<N>> : std::true_type{};
    template<typename = std::enable_if<is_foo<foo<0>>::value>::type>
    Bar(int x) {}
};
```

My problem is that `Bar<double> b(5);` in `main` fails to compile, meaning that `is_foo<foo<0>>::value` turned out to be `false`. However, if I remove `template<typename T>` from the declaration of `class Bar`, then `Bar b(5)` will compile fine. How can I make `is_foo` behave the way I want it to?

Comment: `error C2664: 'Bar<double>::Bar(const Bar<double> &)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'const Bar<double> &'` It tried to call the copy constructor.

Comment: @Arcinde OK, MSVC bug, then.

Answer (score 2):

> My problem is that `Bar<double> b(5);` in main fails to compile,
>   meaning that `is_foo<foo<0>>::value` turned out to be `false`

Not really.

```
+ g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
main.cpp:10:25: error: need 'typename' before 'std::enable_if<Bar<T>::is_foo<Bar<T>::foo<0ul> >::value>::type' because 'std::enable_if<Bar<T>::is_foo<Bar<T>::foo<0ul> >::value>' is a dependent scope
     template<typename = std::enable_if<is_foo<foo<0>>::value>::type>
                         ^
[snip]
+ clang++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp
main.cpp:10:25: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'std::enable_if<is_foo<foo<0> >::value>::type'
    template<typename = std::enable_if<is_foo<foo<0>>::value>::type>
                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                        typename
```

Comment: I added "typename" there. That was not the compile error. The compile error indicated that it tried to call the copy-constructor of Bar, meaning that std::enable_if created a SFINAE.